# Get Content-length minus length of headers

Tags: python, http, request

Python code

```
requests.head("http://...").headers['Content-length']
```

return length of content including size of headers block.

For example

```
import requests
thum = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/VcseIGkyaw8/hqdefault.jpg"
len1 = int(requests.head(thum).headers['Content-length'])
len2 = len(requests.get(thum).text)
print(len1, len2, len1-len2)
```

Result

```
34353 32516 1837
```

But, I want get size of downloading file (**without file download**)

How to do it?

Comment: Content-Length is the length of the payload (body) - i.e. _not_ including the headers https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.2

Comment: That’s a mistake by the server…‽ The Content-Length header should only contain the length of the body.

Comment: Trying to measure the "text" size of a JPG might be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your code, probably the assumption that the "text" size matches the length of the binary.

You can easily check with "curl" that both HEAD and GET return the same Content-Length, and that that matches the size of the JPG.